# lxml returns null as output

Tags: python, html, lxml

so I want to scrape the price of a coin off of a website, but lxml just gives me output as null.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get(f'https://sologenic.org/trade?market=534F4C4F00000000000000000000000000000000%2BrsoLo2S1kiGeCcn6hCUXVrCpGMWLrRrLZz%2FXRP&network=mainnet')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#This will create a list of prices
prices = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/p/text()')


print('Prices: ', prices)
```

I tried from two other websites as well,
1.https://dex.onxrp.com/?project=XREEFS
2.https://xrplcoins.com/coin/XReefs

But am having failures in both of them, it always returns null. I also tried bs4 but same problem.

Comment: It seems that those websites load their content after the initial page is rendered. This is how React and other javascript frameworks work: a simple index.html page is loaded, and this at its turn loads a js scrip that renders elements, get data from other services, ... In your case, the page that you try to load doesn't contain yet all the info that you want to scrape.

Comment: You can try to analyze what happens once the page is loaded, for example what additional ressources are requested, there you'll probably find the price data

Comment: oh, so are there any possible workarounds? I have done it through selenium but selenium just opens chrome and i want something more efficient, i.e just sends requests and fetches the element without opening chrome.

Comment: In practice, by analyzing your page, I see that a request to get the ohlc is done at  https://api.sologenic.org/api/v1/ohlc?symbol=534F4C4F00000000000000000000000000000000%2BrsoLo2S1kiGeCcn6hCUXVrCpGMWLrRrLZz%2FXRP&from=1641989093&to=1647173094&period=1h and you are lucky that they don't seem to have much scrapping prevention, as you get well formatted json data

Comment: the workaround is in this case discovering what ressource is returning the prices (see comment above) and simply querying it. No need for selenium in this case, simply a request.get

Comment: the api.sologenic.or/api/v1/... has the data of all coins or something? Am new to python, and jsons as well, and i opened the link to see all those numbers, so i guess they were the prices of all the coins listed on the website or something?

Comment: no, this seems to be only from one coin. It's the time series of OHLC (Open, High, Low, Close prices) data for this asset. The json contains a list of lists, where the inner list contains the timestamp, the OHLC prices and the volume